# 2 different canvas download as single image file

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, download, merge

In my app, i am trying to merge image which is uploaded by a user with the logo image in 2nd canvas. When I download the image, I am getting logo overlapped on user image

[image]

But what I actually want is this:

[image]

I want to merge 2 separate canvas with each other but side by side and not overlapping each other.

Here is my download canvas code: where `canvas_thumb` has the image user is uploading and `canvas` is the logo image i already have on the page.

```
function downloadCanvas() {
    var bottleCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas_thumb');
    var designCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var bottleContext = bottleCanvas.getContext('2d');
    bottleContext.drawImage(designCanvas, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = "bottle-design.png";
    link.href = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    link.click();
}
```

Please see my example: http://bit.ly/1SYiniX

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: When I download the image, I am getting logo overlapped on user image. Below output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Jvc.png

But what I actually want is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmx4N.png
Ie I want to merge 2 separate canvas with each other but side by side and not overlapping each other.

Comment: `drawImage` has up to nine argument to draw one image onto another. It doesn't magically know where to put the image, you must place it in the right location. see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/canvas_drawimage.asp for information on `drawImage` arguments

Comment: @Blindman67 w3schools is getting better but I still won't recommend it as a reference -> [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com). Better use the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) or the [spec itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage)

Comment: @Andreas I have sent newbies to MDN only to have them return telling me they can't find what there are looking for. w3schools may be uncool for some, but MDN's navigation is unfriendly to those with little to no experience. w3schools information on drawImage is accurate, while MDN has errors on its page (upon looking, not why I did not ref them) I send newbies to w3schools because it is a better designed reference.

Comment: @Blindman67 if you can do it with only `drawImage()` call I want to see it. OP needs a third canvas at the output size he wants in order to draw the two canvases as he shown us...

Comment: basically i need an output on a 3rd canvas size 500 h 480 w. In which I can plaec both the images, one on top and other below 1st image.

Comment: I have both the canvas ready to be merged just dont know which exact code to use as i am new to canvas

Comment: and the code I have used is not merging the canvas the way I want

Answer (score 0):

There is not much info to solve your particular problem, without the two images and the rules. (max/min image size?? is there a required aspect??, or max/min logo scale to avoid artifacts).

I'll assume that the logo must maintain its aspect and can not be trimmed or scaled. There-for the upload image can only be expressed in terms of how much taller it is than the logo image.

The user image can not change aspect and must have as much of it as possible in the upload, clipping out top and bottom or left and right, preserving the center.

So just create a canvas the correct size, draw the logo at the bottom, calculate a scale that will fit the user image. Calculate what part of the user image will fit. Draw that part onto the top.

This ensures that the maximum possible area of the user image is displayed will still keeping the upload image the correct size

```
var imageHeight = 3; // the height of the upload image in terms of
                     // the logos height.
                     // in this case the image will be three times 
                     // the height of the logo

var logoW = canvas.width;
var logoH = canvas.height;


var userImage  // this is the users image

var userW = userImage.width;
var userH = userImage.height;
var userCX = userW / 2; // center of user image
var userCY = userW / 2; // center of user image

// Get the max scale that ensures the user image will 
// fill the space provide
var userScale = Math.max(logoW / userW, logoH * (imageHeight-1) / user.height);

// use the scale to calculate the correct aspect to 
// copy from the user image in user image coordinates
var userClipW = logoW / userScale;
var userClipH = logoH * (imageHeight - 1) / userScale;

// create the new canvas
var uploadImg = document.createElement("canvas");  

// set its size
uploadImg.width = logoW;
uploadImg.height = logoH * imageHeight;

//  get drawing context
ctx = uploadImg.getContext("2d");

// draw logo at the bottom
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, logoH * (imageHeight-1), logoW, logoH);

// draw the user image at the top, taking what can fit from the center, assuming
// that is the requirement, only top and bottom OR left and right are clipped
ctx.drawImage(userImage, userCX - userClipW * 0.5, userCY - userClipH * 0.5, userClipW, userClipH, 0, 0, logoW, logoH * (imageHeight - 1));

// data url for upload.
var dataURL = uploadImg.toDataURL();
```

Comment: basically i need an output on a 3rd canvas size 500 h 480 w. In which I can plaec both the images, one on top and other below 1st image.

Comment: I have both the canvas ready to be merged just dont know which exact code to use as i am new to canvas

Comment: and the code I have used is not merging the canvas the way I want

Comment: The example does create a 3rd image. It is the canvas image called `uploadImg` that I convert to a dataURL at the end. You have given the final image size, and I would assume that the logo is 480 pixels wide. If so then get the logo height (image for bottom part) find out how many times it goes into the 500 pixels for the final image. ie `500/logo.height` then replace the 3 at the very top with that number.